# How to get session id in static method while making callout

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, lwc

I am working on something which includes LWC with tooling API. I wrote this below method which makes a callout. but when I call this method this method from lwc at that time I'm unable to get session Id, but if I call this same method from the developer console then it works fine.

```
Apex Code:
@AuraEnabled 
public static string getList(String fieldName){  
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());
    System.debug('res------>'+UserInfo.getSessionID());
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    req.setEndpoint('callout:Tooling_Query/query/?q=Select+id,Namespaceprefix,developername,TableEnumOrId+FROM+customfield+Where+developername+LIKE\'' +fieldName+ '\'');
    req.setMethod('GET');
    Http h = new Http();
    HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
    System.debug('res------>'+res.getBody());       
    return res.getBody();
}
```

When I call it from lwc it returns this

[{"message":"This session is not valid for use with the REST API","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}]

so, how can I get session-id from lwc, I already set up a Connected App and Named Credential by the name of Tooling_Query
and add URL to remote sites.

please help me here.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Your Apex code called in a Lightning Web Components context *cannot* get an API-enabled Session Id. This is [documented in the Lightning Web Components Dev Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/data_api_calls_apex):

> By security policy, sessions created by Lightning components aren’t enabled for API access. This restriction prevents even your Apex code from making API calls to Salesforce. Using a named credential for specific API calls allows you to carefully and selectively bypass this security restriction.

> The restrictions on API-enabled sessions aren’t accidental. Carefully review any code that uses a named credential to ensure you’re not creating a vulnerability.

The only supported approach is to use a [Named Credential](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_named_credentials.htm) authenticated as a specific user.

---

There is a hack floating around that exploits a Visualforce page to obtain a Session Id from such an Apex context. I do not recommend doing this, especially if you need to access the privileged Tooling API. Use the correct solution and build a Named Credential.

Comment: Sir, I already set up a Named Credential with Authenticated as tyagih@gmail.com Status.
but I'm getting the same result

Comment: Did you use the Named Credential explicitly in your callout? The system won't use it automatically.

Comment: Yes, I did but the same result. I just edit my apex class code above.

Comment: @DavidReed chicken and egg here: I sometimes use the SessionId from Visualforce to call Metadata API to create (now forbidden) or modify (allowed when packaged) NamedCredential. See here: https://github.com/rsoesemann/app-setup/blob/master/force-app/main/default/classes/SetupBackendConnection.cls#L86